# Add Flow Target on IBM-RTC

Tags: commit, target, rtc

I need to add a Target Flow in IBM-RTC and have 2 Streams that are:

1. Stream X
2. Stream Y

And I need you all to be modified / made commits on Stream Y is received by Stream X, but not vice versa. However I accessed the Stream X and added a new Flow Target, indicating the Stream Y. But when I test a Stream Y of commits is not received in the Stream X.

Some feedback to help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Setting a flow target in a stream is purely for "documenting" the relationship between the two streams (mainly when you [compare the two streams to show pending changes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_3.0.1/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_flow_changes_to_stream.html)).
It does not imply any "automatic" operation when delivering in one (and automagically delivering in the other).

One automatic deliver I am aware of is a **[post-build deliver step](https://jazz.net/library/article/649#Example_postBuildDeliver)**, where:

- deliver is made to streamA
- that trigger a build (there is a buil definition using a repo workspace accepting any change sets from streamA)
- a post-build deliver will, if the build succeeds, deliver to another stream.

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/3.0/scm-deliver-streams/images/post-build_deliver.png]